# Looking for case: grad student union cannot negotiate student housing

Tags: court-records, unions

I remember hearing of a court case that ruled that a graduate student union at a university in Illinois (University of Illinois at Urbana-Champagne?) could not negotiate on matters of housing.  However, I cannot find a record of this court case.  Can someone confirm that such a court case exists, and link me to a record of the outcome?

Answer (score 1):

It does not appear to me that such a case exists. A good overview of the issues is present [at the Wikipedia post on the subject](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graduate_student_employee_unionization), whose supporting citation links have mostly rotted.

The National Labor Relations Board (NLRB) denied the right of graduate students at private colleges to unionize in 2004 in a case involving Brown University which was reversed by the NLRB on August 23, 2016.

This did not prevent graduate students at public universities, which are outside the jurisdiction of the NLRB from unionizing, however. Graduate students at the University of Illinois at Urbana-Champagne had their union recognized when the Illinois Court of Appeals held that they were entitled to unionize under state laws related to public employees' unions. This was one of the first cases to successfully recognize a graduate student's union after a long lull in campuses organizing.

The Wikipedia article claims that this was a 2002 decision (this could be the date that the University and the union [reached an agreement](https://www.uigeo.org/2002/06/) ([stipulations](https://humanresources.illinois.edu/assets/docs/AHR/Stipulations.pdf)) regarding who was covered by the union), but the case in question appears to be *Graduate Employees Org. v. Il Educ. Labor*, 315 Ill.App.3d 278, 733 N.E.2d 759, 248 Ill.Dec. 84 (Ill. App. 2000), although it may have taken until 2002 to implement the ruling on remand from the Illinois Court of Appeals. Several other Illinois university graduate student unions were formed in the wake of this decision. A [2004 case](http://caselaw.findlaw.com/il-court-of-appeals/1234913.html) ([ref also](https://casetext.com/case/board-of-trustees-v-ielrb-2)) held that parking issues were beyond the scope of collective bargaining.

I was not able to locate any case litigating their right to negotiate on matters of housing, however.

But, if there is such a case in Illinois, it would be in the state courts of the State of Illinois or Illinois Educational Labor Relations Board (IELRB), in the time period from 2000 to the present. You might also try looking at that graduate student union's website, which might mention such a case if it existed.